# gscript not picking the latest mail while trying to save the csv into google sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, gmail

So I have a google app script where I search a mail based on subject line and then take that csv and update it in an google sheet. This worked fine the first time. But going forward when I got emails with the same subject line it still pick the content of the first email and not the latest .How can I fetch data from the latest mail.

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search("email subject);
  var message = threads[0].getMessages().slice(-1);
  Log.logger(message);
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  Log.logger(message.getAttachments()) ;

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  }
}
```

Comment: I answered your question. Let me know if it works for you as well as it does for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the last or most recent message like that :

```
var message = threads[0].getMessages().slice(-1)
```

Comment: I get this error when I replace the message with what you suggested`TypeError: message.getAttachments is not a function (line 5, file "code")`

Comment: Is there any chance the last message you are getting not to have an attachment? Could you please Log.logger(message) and Log.logger(message.getAttachments()) ?

Comment: new to google app scripts. Does my modified script in the question the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Put both Logger.log methods right after var message and then click on view -> logs and tell me what it shows.

Comment: Sorry I meant Logger.log , not Log.logger .